# Why the c object null in run method?

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I am solving the below interview question. It's throwing a `NullPointerException`, but I do not understand how the value of c is null. I already initialized it in the `go()` method.

```
package swain.javainterviewhub.blogspot.in;

class Chicks{
    synchronized void yack(long id){
        for(int x=1;x<3;x++){
            System.out.println(id+" ");
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}

public class JavaInterviewHub implements Runnable {

    Chicks c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaInterviewHub().go();
    }

    void go(){
        c=new Chicks();
        new Thread(new JavaInterviewHub()).start();
        new Thread(new JavaInterviewHub()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        c.yack(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

}
```

Console:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at swain.javainterviewhub.blogspot.in.JavaInterviewHub.run(JavaInterviewHub.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at swain.javainterviewhub.blogspot.in.JavaInterviewHub.run(JavaInterviewHub.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Each instance of JavaInterviewHub has its own c field?

Comment: `new Thread(new JavaInterviewHub()).start();` - The `JavaInterviewHub` created here does not have its `c` field initialized.

Comment: @immibis can you please  briefly explain what happening here

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Chicks.yack()` is `synchronized`, you probably meant for both threads to use the same instance of `Chicks`, which means you probably meant for both threads to use the same instance of `JavaInterviewHub`, in which case you probably meant to start both threads with the instance that was created in `main()`.

If that's all true, then you need to use `this` when creating the threads:

```
void go(){
    c=new Chicks();
    new Thread(this).start();
    new Thread(this).start();
}
```

---

As for the question of when to create an instance of `Chicks`, and therefore assign a value to `c`, you have 3 choices:

1. Leave the code as-is. A bit obscure, but *valid*.
2. Do it in a constructor.
3. Do it when declaring `c`. *Easiest*.

*Option 2:* Constructor

```
private JavaInterviewHub() {
    this.c = new Chicks();
}
```

*Option 3:* Declaration

```
private final Chicks c = new Chicks();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a thread like this:

```
new Thread(new JavaInterviewHub()).start();
```

A new instance of `JavaInterviewHub` is created. In this instance `c` is not set anywhere, so when the `run` method is executed, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

One way to solve the issue is to initialize `c` in `JavaInterviewHub`'s constructor. Another would be to initialize `c` where it's declared. See the acepted answer for more information.

Comment: If you do that, then you have a total of 3 instances of both `JavaInterviewHub` and `Chicks`, and there's no need to *synchronize* `yack()`.

Comment: The reason why the program creates multiple instances of `JavaInterviewHub` is not because it "creates new threads like this..."  It's because of the `new JavaInterviewHub()`.  I realize that's the bulk of the "like this" that you were talking about, but these newbies need a lot of hand-holding.  Don't confuse 'em by saying "when you create a new thread" if creating the thread is not the problem.